# File read never completes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to serve static files through nodeJS and I am able to serve the images and html page but when I request the stylesheet and javascript file the request stay on pending and never end. Bellow are snippets from the relevant part of the code, and a screenshot of the network.

[Network tab in developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/231sM.png)

Node JS part:

index.js

```
"use strict";

const http = require('http');

const requestModule = require('./Modules/Request');
const header = require('./Modules/Header');

const server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    switch (request.method) {
        case 'GET':
            requestModule.getRequest(request, response);
            break;
        case 'POST':
            requestModule.postRequest(request, response);
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(501, header['plain']);
            response.end();
            break;
    }
});

server.listen(8119);
```

Request module

```
    "use strict";

const url = require('url');
const fs = require("fs");
const crypto = require('crypto');
const header = require('./Header').header;
const helper = require('./Helper');

module.exports.getRequest = function (request, response) {
  let sentURL = url.parse(request.url, true);
  let path = sentURL.pathname;
  let content = sentURL.query;
  let body = '';

  request.on('data', function (chunk) {
    body += chunk;
  });

  request.on('end', function () {
    switch (path) {
      case '/': //THIS PART WORKS
        fs.readFile('../Frontend/index.html', function (err, data) {
          if (err) throw err;
          response.writeHead(200, header['html']);
          response.write(data);
          response.end();
        });
        break;
      case '/style.css':
        fs.readFileSync('../Frontend/style.css', function (err, data) {
          if (err) throw err;
          response.writeHead(200, header['css']);
          response.write(data);
          response.end();
        });
        break;
      case '/main.js':
        fs.readFileSync('../Frontend/_main.js', function (err, data) {
          if (err) throw err;
          response.writeHead(200, header['plain']);
          response.write(data);
          response.end();
        });
        break;
```

Header module:

```
    plain: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/javascript',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
},
html: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
},
css: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/css',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `fs.readFileSync` for the CSS and JavaScript, instead of `fs.readFile`. The `Sync` version never calls the callback, because it's synchronous (it *returns* the data instead). Just change `fs.readFileSync` to `fs.readFile` in those two case branches.